# Is there a way to prevent Android Studio from saving undo history after file close?

Tags: android-studio

When I close a file (not close Android Studio) and re-open that file, I do not want Android Studio to save its undo history. Is there a way to prevent Android Studio from saving file undo history after file close?

As in NetBeans (or most editors for that matter), I like it that I cannot undo anything in a file once I close and re-open that file. Is there some setting I can change or some config file I can modify to prevent Android Studio from remembering file undo history after I close that file? I couldn't find anything obvious in the "Settings...", but I could have overlooked it.

Answer (score 1):

You've an interesting question. I'm also overlooked all settings and can't find anything similar.

But I find, that Android Studio (based on IntelliJ IDEA) have special mechanism called [Local History](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/using-local-history.html). It locally stores all your changes. And accroding to the documentation:

> Local history is cleared when you install a new version of IntelliJ
>   IDEA or when you invalidate caches. Therefore, check in the changes to
>   your version control system before performing these operations.

I didn't find any other ways to clear Local History, so I think there are no ones.

Answer (score 0):

On the main menu, choose File | Invalidate Caches/Restart.